# Display flex isnt working outside of codepen

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

I was trying to build a responsive two-column layout in Codepen, which worked. The layout is pretty simple and consists of a youtube video and some text.

However, when I tried to implement it on my website, it didn't work... Here my code, hopefully, someone is able to help me :O

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  .flex-container {
    gap: 10px;
    @media (min-width: 56.25em){
      display: flex;
    }
  }

  .main-content {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .sidebar {
    flex: 1;
  }

  .videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    height: 0;
  }
  .videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <main class="flex-container">
    <section class="main-content">
      <h2>Sidebar</h2>
      <div class="videoWrapper"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/eX2qFMC8cFo" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    </section>

    <aside class="sidebar">
      <h2>Main Content</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam placeat cumque exercitationem vitae nisi tenetur delectus praesentium doloremque, quibusdam nemo maxime laudantium et possimus pariatur doloribus excepturi. Veritatis ex numquam inventore odit dolorum mollitia dolorem, itaque atque non ratione molestias a repellat ullam corporis quisquam ipsa sit iure tempore nulla.
      </p>
   </aside>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

When I inspect the code within the Chrome Inspector, it clearly shows, that the command "display: flex;" isn't working, but I don't know why and I can't find a solution.
[Screenshot of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm74t.png)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are using a CSS preprocessor like SASS or LESS, you cannot nest a media query inside the "main rule" for a certain selector. In your screenshot you can see that the browser tries to interpret the first line of that media query `@media (min-width: 56.25em){` as a separate rule by *adding* a semicolon at its end `;`, which won't work.

So you have to write the main rule and the media query separately, using the same CSS selector again inside the media query:

```
.flex-container {
  gap: 10px;
  
}
@media (min-width: 56.25em) {
   .flex-container {
     display: flex;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change This CSS

```
.flex-container {
  gap: 10px;
  
}
@media (min-width: 56.25em){
   .flex-container{
     display: flex;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to write something like this for your CSS, you have typing error:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

  @media (min-width: 56.25em){
   .flex-container {
     gap: 20px;
    }
  }
```